# How can i add another value in a column while copying a row from a table to another table?

Tags: mysql

I want to copy a row from table Items to table Orders. Both table has the same column Item_name and Price but table Orders have an additional column date.
I know how to copy a row to another table but i want to copy and insert a value on column date and column quantity at the same time.

Comment: please provide a sample code of your tables and a draft of your query

Comment: you can probably do `insert into orders select item_name, price, now() from items`

Answer (score 1):

Ok So your column count from `Orders` table is not matching with column count from `items` table since you have one extra column `date` in Orders. And you want to enter value in column date at same time.
So the following query will work.

```
insert into Orders(Item_name,Price,date) select Item_name,Price,NOW() from items
```

So this will populate all records from `items` along with those record it will insert current date time to date.

Comment: actually, i am not only adding the date, im also adding a value in the column quantity.
thanksfor the help

Comment: ok so your saying you have one more extra column 'quantity' inside Orders table ??